# iOS 14 Device cannot track App Install on Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, tracking

Hi I am trying to track the app installs on Facebook for some reason is not tracking properly on iOS on my device with iOS 14, I already installed the latest SDK as facebook ask and I am initialising the SDK on AppDelegate, I read thats starting on iOS 14 you need to ask the user for permission to track them but only in the case you want to serve ads to them right? I just want to track the app install! Any ideas?